# What are the routes to obtain a PR in Australia after finishing a PhD degree?

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia

I'm currently doing a PhD in Philosophy in Canada, and I have a high chance of getting a PR after graduation through various pathways offered by the government. But I've been offered a much better position in Australia (PhD in the same field) which is, career-wise, a great opportunity to take on, but I'm having doubts if I should miss the easy PR opportunity here by moving to Australia. I've heard obtaining a PR in Australia is a lot harder than in Canada.

What are the pathways and chances of getting a PR in Australia after finishing a PhD in Philosophy? What are the chances?

To illustrate what I'm looking for: in Canada, after finishing a program of at least 2 years (so, PhD programs included) one is given up to three years
of Postgraduate Work Permit. I can then can get a PR, for instance, by going through a Provincial Nomination Program, which (given the points I will have due to age, degree, etc) needs a minimum of 6 months of full-time employment in a closely related field after graduation, in the three-year time period, or apply for PR through an Express Entry program, which needs a minimum of one-year full-time employment in almost *any* field (e.g., even tech jobs) no matter your education topic, in the same period of time. Are such pathways available and/or feasible in Australia?

Please let me know if you have any questions about other specifics of my case.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing ?

Comment: Also https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/working-in-australia/skill-occupation-list